# Stroyboard Issue in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I am working on Xamarin.iOS Project. when I open My Storyboard suddenly All ViewController is Vanished And storyboard display only UINavigationController. I don't know what is happening. In Document Outline. All ViewController are there see the Right Panel of the ScreenShot.

[image]

I will `restart my Mac`. `clean and Rebuild` project. `Remove bin and obj` folder but nothing is help to me.

Any Help will be Appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to restart XCode ? cause sometime it happen to me and i try so it will resolve my problem

Comment: @ravi.p I am working on Xamarin. Still you say then I will try..

Comment: @ravi.p thanks that work for me. Even in Xamarin Project too.

Comment: can i post as answer so other can get also help from it.. ;)

Comment: @ravi.p ya you can because it help and also help other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially all screen are there but they are not showing so you just need to

> **Quit your Xcode and try and still it is not showing so repeat this process cause some time it will take 2-3 times so get recover all
>   screen in to it.**